# python selenium - Cant find the element of sign in button

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation

I'm trying to create an automation test in Asos (for practice purpose only) however I'm having a hard time locating this sign-in element...

I need to click on that sign-in button.

these are the element I got in inspect:

```
a class="_1336dMe _1uUU2Co _1336dMe _1uUU2Co" href="https://my.asos.com/my-account?
lang=en-GB&amp;store=COM&amp;country=GB&amp;keyStoreDataversion=3pmn72e-27" 
data-testid="signin-link" tabindex="-1">Sign In
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Is it in an `iFrame`?

Comment: im not sure.. but i am looking for the element of sign in button in a pop up

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to find this button on Google Maps. Is the sign in button on a pop up window? Then the problem is becuse you have to change between frames.

Here is a code sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver path')
url = 'url'

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="consent-bump"]/div/div[1]/iframe')))
agree = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span'))) 
agree.click()

#back to the main page
driver.switch_to_default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchboxinput"]'))).send_keys('gostilne')
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchbox-searchbutton"]')))
search.click()
```

Make shure that the xpath for frames and buttons is correct.

Comment: then the problem is becuse you have to change between frames

Comment: I have no idea where the iframe is. I post the below element that I got when I inspect it.

Comment: after i locate the myaccount I want to click on Sign in button which I'm having a hard time to do it  because I cant find an element ..